# AWS Redshift - Frequently accessed/queried tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way for us to check how frequently a table has been accessed/queried in AWS redshift?
Frequency can be daily/monthly/every hour or whatever.. Can some one help me?

It could be sql queries using system tables from AWS Redshift or some python script. What is the best way?

Comment: I am aware we can use tables like pg_class_info and pg_namespace to come up with ways.. I am trying to see if there is a better solution..